# Is it possible to find the .NET class that uses my class as a generic type?

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I have a DTO class:

```
public class MyDto {...}
```

and a validator that extends a generic validator of my class:

```
public class MyDtoValidator: AbstractValidator<MyDto>
```

In my code I know the typeof MyDto (and can create an instance if need be). Based on this type, is it possible to get to the type of MyDtoValidator using reflection? I know the assembly and the exact namespace where the validator is located, if that helps. I realize there can be any number of types that inherit from `AbstractValidator<MyDto>`, but in my case there will always be one, so even if I get a list I get a list of one.

I can find it by class name if I stick "Validator" at the end of my class (and I may end up having to do that) but I'm trying to limit dependence on naming conventions and string concatenation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use linq to filter the defined types of an assembly:

```
yourValidatorAssembly.DefinedTypes
    .Where(x => x.BaseType?.IsGenericType == true && x.BaseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(AbstractValidator<>))
```

Edit: If you need to look multiple levels, use this instead:

```
yourValidatorAssembly.DefinedTypes
    .Where(x => x.GetHierachicalTypes().Any(y => y.IsGenericType && y.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(AbstractValidator<>)))

public static class TypeExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<Type> GetHierachicalTypes(this Type type)
    {
        while (type != null)
        {
            yield return type;
            type = type.BaseType;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but in your first code snippet I can't figure out where MyDto type enters into the select. There will be many classed derived from AbstractValidator<SomeOtherDto> and I need the one that validates MyDtoo.

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out: && x.BaseType.GetGenericArguments().First() == MyDto